# iOS-Charts : minOffset not working

Tags: ios-charts

When I am setting minOffset to 0, it's not removing the extra padding/margin in the bar chart.

Is there any way to hide that space?
attached the screenshot, I like to remove that extra space/padding/margin from the top.

and if you add zero to one of the bars then this margin will increase. Attaching the screenshot for that too

[Extra spacing on top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkoMG.jpg)

[Margin/space increase if one of the bars value is zero](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAy1l.jpg)

Configuration parameters of graphs

```
func setUpGraph() {
    self.vwChart.chartDescription?.enabled = false
    self.vwChart.drawGridBackgroundEnabled = false
    self.vwChart.drawBordersEnabled = false
    self.vwChart.dragEnabled = false;
    self.vwChart.setScaleEnabled(true)
    self.vwChart.pinchZoomEnabled = false
    self.vwChart.minOffset = 0
    self.vwChart.animate(yAxisDuration: 1.0)

    self.vwChart.xAxis.enabled = false
    self.vwChart.leftAxis.enabled = false
    self.vwChart.leftAxis.inverted = true
    self.vwChart.rightAxis.enabled = false
    self.vwChart.legend.enabled = false

    self.vwChart.xAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
    self.vwChart.leftAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
    self.vwChart.rightAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false

    self.vwChart.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
    self.vwChart.leftAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
    self.vwChart.rightAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false

    self.vwChart.xAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false
    self.vwChart.xAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false
    self.vwChart.leftAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false
    self.vwChart.rightAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false
}

func setGraphData() {
    var yVals:Array<BarChartDataEntry> = Array<BarChartDataEntry>()

    yVals.append(BarChartDataEntry(x: 0, y: 10))
    yVals.append(BarChartDataEntry(x: 1, y: 5))
    yVals.append(BarChartDataEntry(x: 2, y: 30))
    yVals.append(BarChartDataEntry(x: 3, y: 10))
    yVals.append(BarChartDataEntry(x: 4, y: 50))
    yVals.append(BarChartDataEntry(x: 5, y: 15))
    yVals.append(BarChartDataEntry(x: 6, y: 70))
    yVals.append(BarChartDataEntry(x: 7, y: 20))
    yVals.append(BarChartDataEntry(x: 8, y: 90))
    yVals.append(BarChartDataEntry(x: 9, y: 25))
    yVals.append(BarChartDataEntry(x: 10, y: 110))
    yVals.append(BarChartDataEntry(x: 11, y: 30))
    yVals.append(BarChartDataEntry(x: 12, y: 130))
    yVals.append(BarChartDataEntry(x: 13, y: 35))
    yVals.append(BarChartDataEntry(x: 14, y: 150))
    yVals.append(BarChartDataEntry(x: 15, y: 40))
    yVals.append(BarChartDataEntry(x: 16, y: 170))
    yVals.append(BarChartDataEntry(x: 17, y: 50))
    yVals.append(BarChartDataEntry(x: 18, y: 190))

    let barChartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(values: yVals, label: "")
    barChartDataSet.colors = [UIColor.violetBlue]

    let barChartData = BarChartData(dataSet: barChartDataSet)
    barChartData.barWidth = 0.4
    barChartData.setDrawValues(false)

    self.vwChart.data = barChartData
}
```

Comment: Please show the code you're using so that the root of the problem can be traced

Comment: Thaks for the reply. Here is the screenshot of the code
https://screencast.com/t/IsJovUEAe8

Comment: Edit your question, copy the code and paste it into there with formatting so that anyone coming to assist or with the same problem can see everything in one place. As it is, after discovering the link, someone has to type out a lot of code and that will take more time than necessary to assist you.

Comment: Please add some code related to Charts configration so we can get idea how you are setting your chart.

Comment: I have added the configuration code and the data i am giving to the chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to add the below line to line up the bars :

```
self.vwChart.leftAxis.axisMinimum = 0.0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You can use the spaceBottom/spaceTop Property for removing space.

```
self.vwChart.leftAxis.spaceBottom = 0.0
self.vwChart.rightAxis.spaceBottom = 0.0
```

Thanks.
Hope this will help.